# Helm Yaml configuration

Tags: json, asp.net-core, kubernetes, helm3

I have a problem. I have a json as below.

```
 "IpRateLimiting": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "60s",
        "Limit": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
```

and I have a helm values.yaml as below.

```
    IPRATELIMITING_ENABLEENDPOINTRATELIMITING: "true"
    IPRATELIMITING_STACKBLOCKEDREQUESTS: "false"
    IPRATELIMITING_HTTPSTATUSCODE: "429"
    IPRATELIMITING_GENERALRULES:
    - ENDPOINT: "*"
      PERIOD: "61s"
      LIMIT: "2"
```

and I have a helm config.yaml as below.

```
  IPRATELIMITING__ENABLEENDPOINTRATELIMITING: {{ .Values.configMap.data.IPRATELIMITING_ENABLEENDPOINTRATELIMITING | quote }}
  IPRATELIMITING__STACKBLOCKEDREQUESTS: {{ .Values.configMap.data.IPRATELIMITING_STACKBLOCKEDREQUESTS | quote }}
  IPRATELIMITING__HTTPSTATUSCODE: {{ .Values.configMap.data.IPRATELIMITING_HTTPSTATUSCODE | quote }}
  IPRATELIMITING__GENERALRULES: {{ .Values.configMap.data.IPRATELIMITING_GENERALRULES | quote }}
```

I can't read GeneralRules (json array) values from here. How can I modify my helm config?

Comment: What does the final block go with (a ConfigMap, a Pod spec's environment block, something else)?  How are these three parts connected in the deployed application?  Helm includes both `toYaml` and [`toJson`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) template functions which might help this along.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze this parts provides management of env variables. Actually I can read IPRATELIMITING_ENABLEENDPOINTRATELIMITING, IPRATELIMITING__STACKBLOCKEDREQUESTS and  IPRATELIMITING__HTTPSTATUSCODE but just cant read IPRATELIMITING__GENERALRULES. I think, I cant define  config yaml as expected.

Comment: An environment variable's value is always a string.  How do you want the nested object to be represented within that string?